# Gradient fill area under curve

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I want to fill the area under curve with the optical spectrum colors, getting a plot like this.

[image]

This is what I tried

```
 ggplot(bq, aes(x=w.length, y=s.e.irrad)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=w.length, yend=0, colour=abs(w.length)^0.7*sign(w.length))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low=scales::muted("blue"), 
                         mid=scales::muted("green"), 
                         high=scales::muted("red"))
```

getting this

[image]

Also tried with geom_area

```
ggplot(bq, aes(x = w.length, y = s.e.irrad))+
  geom_area(fill = "steelblue") #steelblue is for example
```

But can't fill with gradient

My dataframe has wavelengths in x and Irradiance in y

Comment: How about something like `scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("#0325ff", "#4afd00", "#ff0005"))`?

Comment: I think if you wanna try to somewhat accurately visualise your spectral colors, you should not interpolate between only three colors, but in a much denser way. Anyways, please provide some sample data and make a reproducible question, otherwise it's difficult to help you, and more importantly, people in the future will not benefit from this question.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is the R package `ggspectra`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should be close to what you're looking for. The trick is to use `scale_color_identity` for the `geom_segment`, and passing to the color aesthetic an RGB string that represents each wavelength in your data frame.

```r
ggplot(bq, aes(x=w.length, y=s.e.irrad)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=w.length, yend=0, colour = nm_to_RGB(w.length)),
               size = 1) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image]

Or if you want a more muted appearance:

```r
ggplot(bq, aes(x=w.length, y=s.e.irrad)) +
  geom_area(fill = "black") +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=w.length, yend=0, 
                   colour = nm_to_RGB(w.length)),
               size = 1, alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image]

The only drawback being that you need to define `nm_to_RGB`: the function that converts a wavelength of light into a hex-string to represent a color. I'm not sure there's a "right" way to do this, but one possible implementation (that I translated from the javascript function [here](https://academo.org/demos/wavelength-to-colour-relationship/)) would be:

```r
nm_to_RGB <- function(wavelengths){
  sapply(wavelengths, function(wavelength) {
  red <- green <- blue <- 0  
  if((wavelength >= 380) & (wavelength < 440)){
    red <- -(wavelength - 440) / (440 - 380)
    blue <- 1
  }else if((wavelength >= 440) & (wavelength<490)){
    green <- (wavelength - 440) / (490 - 440)
    blue <- 1
  }else if((wavelength >= 490) && (wavelength<510)){
    green <- 1
    blue = -(wavelength - 510) / (510 - 490)
  }else if((wavelength >= 510) && (wavelength<580)){
    red = (wavelength - 510) / (580 - 510)
    green <- 1
  }else if((wavelength >= 580) && (wavelength<645)){
    red = 1
    green <- -(wavelength - 645) / (645 - 580)
  }else if((wavelength >= 645) && (wavelength<781)){
    red = 1
  }
  if((wavelength >= 380) && (wavelength<420)){
    fac <- 0.3 + 0.7*(wavelength - 380) / (420 - 380)
  }else if((wavelength >= 420) && (wavelength<701)){
    fac <- 1
  }else if((wavelength >= 701) && (wavelength<781)){
    fac <- 0.3 + 0.7*(780 - wavelength) / (780 - 700)
  }else{
    fac <- 0
  }
  do.call(rgb, as.list((c(red, green, blue) * fac)^0.8))
  })
}
```

Obviously, I don't have your data set, but the following code creates a plausible set of data over the correct ranges:

---

**Data**

```r
set.seed(10)

bq <- setNames(as.data.frame(density(sample(rnorm(5, 600, 120)))[c("x", "y")]),
               c("w.length", "s.e.irrad"))

bq$s.e.irrad <- bq$s.e.irrad * 1e5
```

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug. I've just made an R package, [wavecolour](https://github.com/roaldarbol/wavecolour) which does just this, with `ggplot` scales.
It's not yet on CRAN, so is installed from Github:

```r
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("roaldarbol/wavecolour")
```

Here's a minimal example, with a plot inspired by @Allan Cameron's solution:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(wavecolour)

# Create data
wavl <- seq(from = 300, to = 790, length.out = 500)
wavl_sin <- sin((wavl * pi) / (180)) + 1.5
wavl <- bind_cols(wavl, wavl_sin)
names(wavl) <- c("wavelength", "intensity")

# Create plot
ggplot(wavl, aes(wavelength, intensity)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=wavelength, yend=0, colour = wavelength), size = 1) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_wavelength() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: See plot here - I don't have enough credit to embed images yet]

Comment: Kind of nice +1 - the way you're coding it seems to be on CRAN, which it isn't - please provide the additional required lines.  also, a few curious questions (sorry, I am an eye researcher). On what is your conversion of wavelengths to hex / Rgb based? Would be a great added information for your package. How is it different than the ggspectra package (which was mentioned in a previous comment)?

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It's is my first attempt at a CRAN package (will submit soon), so appreciate any feedback. The conversion is based on old Fortran code by Dan Bruton, as written and visualised here: http://www.physics.sfasu.edu/astro/color/spectra.html. 
As far as I can tell, `ggspectra` doesn't supply colour or fill scales, however, I think the same effect can be achieved using that package too. The colour conversion seems different, with Dan's conversion looking a bit more like what I'd expect.

Comment: good luck for the CRAN package!! It can be quite painful - don't fret! You will make it eventually :)